# If account type x include y?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to direct one set of users `Basic` to one type of profile page `mod_profile.php` and another set of users `upgraded` to a different profile page `mod_account.php`. So far, I have this but it seems to be having trouble. I am getting errors when I open up `mod_account.php` about it not being able to redeclare certain functions from `mod_profile` or the other profile page, but I dont understand why, I only want one of the pages to load for each user type.

Can someone please advise me what I am doing wrong?

My `profile.php` page:

```
 <?php
    $page_title = "Profile";
    include('includes/header.php');
    include ('includes/mod_login/login_form2.php');     

    // GET PROFILE ID FROM URL
    if (isset ($_GET['id'])) {
        $profile_id = $_GET['id'];
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    $user_info_set = get_user_info();
    if (!$user = mysql_fetch_array($user_info_set)) {
        include ('includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php');
    } else if (!isset($profile_id)) {
        include("includes/mod_profile/mod_noprofile.php");
    }

    $profile_info_set = get_profile_info();
    while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($profile_info_set)) 

    if (isset ($profile_id))
    if ($user['account_status'] == "Active") {
        include("includes/mod_profile/mod_profile.php");
    }

    $profile_info3_set = get_profile_info3();

    while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($profile_info3_set)) 
        if (isset ($profile_id))
        if ($user['account_type'] == "Basic

    ----------

    ") {
        include("includes/mod_profile/mod_account.php");
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <?php include('includes/footer.php');?>
```

my defined function code:

```
 // profile functions
        function get_user_info() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_users
                        WHERE id = \"$profile_id\"
                        AND account_status = \"Active\" ";
            $user_info_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($user_info_set);
            return $user_info_set;
        }

function get_profile_info() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_profiles, ptb_users
                        WHERE ptb_profiles.user_id = \"$profile_id\"
                        AND account_type = \"Basic\"
                        AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id";
            $profile_info_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($profile_info_set);
            return $profile_info_set;

            }


            function get_profile_info3() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_profiles, ptb_users
                        WHERE ptb_profiles.user_id = \"$profile_id\"
                        AND account_type = \"Upgraded\"
                        AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id";
            $profile_info3_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($profile_info3_set);
            return $profile_info3_set;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your problem is that you are at some point loading the same file twice and redefining functions. Php has a solution for this :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

```
include_once "functions.php"
```

This means that in the loading of any page, functions.php will only be loaded if it hasn't been already.

Let me know if that goes somewhere towards solving your problem. What file is the second block of code?